# Streams and procedures with variable number of arguments in Scheme

Tags: dictionary, stream, scheme, r5rs

I'm trying to create a stream version of map that takes a variable number of streams as argument. The problem I have is that I want it to handle streams of various size, and that it will terminate when one of them is empty. If i was dealing with lists instead of streams I would just do like this:

```
if (member? '() args)
   '()
```

But since this materializes the whole stream each time, I guess it defeats the purpose? I can't seem to think of any other way to check if one of the streams are empty than to to it like this.

Comment: What implementation are you using?

Comment: You might enjoy [SRFI-41](https://programmingpraxis.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/streams.pdf), which describes a stream version of map, as well as many other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between stream version and ordinary is that you need to use `stream-cons`, etc. You can still have a list of streams instead of a list of lists so your little check can be written:

```scm
(if (memq stream-null args)
    stream-null
    (stream-cons <??> <??>))
```

It does **not** materialize the stream since `args` is a list of streams. Thus every stream gets checked for being the empty stream and that's a very simple `eq?` test (hench I changed it to `memq`)